# constructor not displaying values in c++ switch statement

Tags: c++, constructor, switch-statement

Hi im trying to build a program for this ferry to keep track of the free space but im stuck with trying to output the values the user gave in inside a constructor. So the problem occurs in case 5 where im trying to output it. The for loop doesnt work cuz it will break it but a while loop didnt work either. Also creating a seperate function didnt work. Help would be really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct cars {
    int carlength, carcount;
    string registrationnumber;
    int carseats;
} caaars[100];

void printcars(cars car);  

int n, x;

int main()
{
    int loop = 0;
    string mystr, mystr1, mystr2;
    int ferrylength;
    cout << "The Ferry Program\n\n";

    cout << "Please enter the length of the ferry in meters: ";
    cin >> ferrylength;

    while (loop == 0) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Choose a vehicle \n\n";
        cout << "1: Car.\n";
        cout << "2: Bus.\n";
        cout << "3: Lorrie.\n";
        cout << "4: Digger.\n";
        cout << "5: To print a report.\n";
        cout << "6: To close the program.\n\n";
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {

        case 1:{
            cout << "\nEnter the amount of cars needed to be placed on the ferry: ";
            cin >> x;
            cin.ignore();
            while (n != x)
            {

                cout << "\nPlease enter the length of the car in metres: ";
                getline(cin, mystr);
                stringstream(mystr) >> caaars[n].carlength; //for integers.

                cout << "\nPlease enter the Registration number: ";
                getline(cin, caaars[n].registrationnumber); //For strings and both

                cout << "\nPlease enter the amount of seats in the car: ";
                getline(cin, mystr2);
                stringstream(mystr2) >> caaars[n].carseats;



                n++;
            }
        }

            break;
        case 2:


            break;
        case 3:

            break;

        case 4: 

            break;

        case 5: 
        {
            int l;
             l = 0;
            for (l = 0; l < x; l++) 

                printcars(caaars[n]);
        }

            break;

        case 6: 
            loop++;
            break;
        }// end of while loop. 
    }
    return 0;
}

void printcars(cars car) {
    int p = 1;

    system("cls");
    cout << "Car ";
    cout << p; cout << ":" << endl;
    cout << "\nThe registration number is: ";
    cout << car.registrationnumber << endl; 
    cout << "\nThe car length is: ";
    cout << car.carlength << endl;
    cout << "\nAmount of car seats: ";
    cout << car.carseats << endl;


    p++;
}
```

Comment: `caaars[n]` - are you *sure* that subscript is correct ?

Comment: @WhozCraig well it was working before I added the switch case, but looking back at it that might be a problem. Do you have any idea of a better way?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah so I did some tests and that subscript is working in other situations. Thanks for your time

Comment: Where's the constructor that you are talking about?  The `struct cars` doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: You are printing the same `caaars` value in the loop: `printcars(caaars[n]);`.  Maybe you want `printcars(caaars[l]);`?

Comment: What "constructor"? There is no constructor here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating using `n` while you should use `l` instead:

```
case 5: 
{
    int l;
        l = 0;
    for (l = 0; l < x; l++) 

        printcars(caaars[l]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work. However, it still doesnt output more than one car. I've tried to change it to while loops at cetera. I think it is because of the break within the case.. Do you maybe have any clue how to fix that as well? Thank you!

Comment: Having system("cls") inside printcars function clears the screen. So, just take it outside the function. Put it in case 5 statement before calling printcars

Comment: Thank you sir, that actually did the job your help is much much appreciated